# Is there any relationship between Open Data Protocol and SOAP?

Tags: wcf

What is the role of Open Data Protocol and SOAP in WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between OData and SOAP. OData is protocol for updating and retreving data. It is built on top of REST services and it uses ATOM or JSON message formatting. SOAP is general protocol for exchanging structured information of any type.